# Aurelia just for client side (front-end) data binding

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I just started to learn about `Aurelia`. But the problem is I'm a PHP developer so I just want to use it in front-end and I don't want to (can't) install node.js on my server or other requirement for back-end.

First, I wanted to use Angular for fetching data from server in `JSON` then adding it to my page but after reading about `Aurelia` I decided to use it. So how can I use it without any server implementation.

I know that in `Aurelia` we use `TypeScript`  so we need a `transpiler`. how can I convert my code into `JS` then upload it on server for client to use it?

Answer (score 1):

There are ready to use bundles here: https://github.com/aurelia/aurelia

Copy the `src` folder, `scripts` folder and `index.html` into your project and you'll be up and running.

This kind of setup would not be suitable for production because the transpilation from TypeScript to JavaScript is happening in the browser (vs ahead of time, as part of your build process).

A better approach would be to use the aurelia-cli to do your development- this requires node *on your development machine only*. When you're ready to deploy copy the contents of the scripts folder and the index.html to your production server. Node is not required at runtime. The output is static files: html, css and javascript.

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/1

Comment: I did the `todo` example from aurelia doc. How can I do the transpilation ahead of time ?